# How do I change the speed of pedestrians during exit after setting up a speed from the PedSource when pedestrians enter using anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

Using pedSource I have set up the comfortable and initial speed to be around 1 m/s when entering the building but I would like to increase the pedestrians speed when it is exiting to around 2 m/s using pedGoTo. How do I do that with anylogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom *Pedestrian Type* and use this in your flowchart:

[image: pedSource Settings]

You can then access the function `ped.setComfortableSpeed(2)`, to set the speed to a new value before you trigger the evacuation movement.

An example model can be run (and source files can be downloaded) [here](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/7726ca6b-c232-40eb-aee0-6c1a760913f1?mode=SETTINGS).

Comment: Hi I actually still cannot get the pedestrians to move to a different speed when evacuating. The pedestrians still move with a speed of 1 m/s. I want them to go to exit at a speed of 2 m/s after waiting at a certain place (pedWait). I am trying to conduct an evacuation simulation. Thank you

Comment: You are a life saver. I might have more questions in the future and I Hope you will be able to help me with it. Its for my project that I am currently working on.

Comment: Sure, just post seperate questions for each topic on StackOverflow with the AnyLogic tag. I am sure me or one of the other AnyLogic enthusiasts will be able to help you ;)